# Host can't ping docker container on ipvlan l2

Tags: docker, networking, ip, subnet

I've been avoiding other docker network types for a while, wanted to get started so followed a few tutorials. Ipvlan l2 seems to work super intuitively on every site, video or tutorial I've seen or visited. But I can't figure what I'm doing wrong. I have the following docker-compose file.

```
networks:
    ipvlan:
        driver: ipvlan
        driver_opts:
            ipvlan_mode: l2
            parent: wlp3s0
        ipam:
            config:
                - gateway: 10.0.0.1
                  subnet: 10.0.0.0/24
services:
    www:
        image: test/nginx:latest
        networks:
            ipvlan:
                ipv4_address: 10.0.0.140
        # ports:
        #     - 80
        #     - 443
```

From within the container I can ping the internet and gateway, but can't ping container from host. Since this resides in the same subnet I though it would have worked out of the box without creating any link, routes or addresses... I'm aware that my needs fit more with l3 ipvlan but can't proceed without knowing what's going on?

```
##### from host to container #####
$ ping 10.0.0.140
PING 10.0.0.140 (10.0.0.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.54 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.54 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.54 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

```
/ $ ping -c 4 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: seq=0 ttl=42 time=9.459 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: seq=1 ttl=42 time=4.156 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: seq=2 ttl=42 time=2.373 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: seq=3 ttl=42 time=5.092 ms

--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 2.373/5.270/9.459 ms
/ $ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=42 time=56.992 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=42 time=57.372 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=42 time=54.327 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=3 ttl=42 time=55.030 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 54.327/55.930/57.372 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on docker documentation there is a note which says that due to security, it will not let you ping the host.  It does not go into detail what else it limits, but I get the feel that it is more than just icmp.

```html
 #NOTE: the containers can NOT ping the underlying host interfaces as
 #they are intentionally filtered by Linux for additional isolation.
```

this is from [Docker Documentation for IPvLAN](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/ipvlan/)